# Have gas fees the same usage on Polygon/Matic as Ethereum?

Tags: pending-transactions, polygon, failed-transaction

I've noticed that recently, Polygon blockchain becomes too slow at specific hours of the day. My transactions getting queued for several hours and then only some of them being sent to the blockchain (which of course all of them fail after such a long pending time!). I tested several different providers and all of them seem to have the same issue. I even tried to increase the gas fees by a large margin, but I got no progress.
I have two questions:
1- Is there a congestion on Polygon/Matic similar to Ethereum mainnet?
2- Why increasing gas fees does not help my transactions getting processed immediately? (In the Ethereum mainnet, even at peak times, I always can easily include my transactions within a few next blocks by increasing the gas fees).

Answer (score 1):

> 1- Is there a congestion on Polygon/Matic similar to Ethereum mainnet?

Yes. Polygon blocks are full. [You can read more information here on Scaling issues for EVM post](https://capitalgram.com/posts/scaling-evm/).

> 2- Why increasing gas fees does not help my transactions getting processed immediately?

It should still help. Because the question does not include details about the transaction, what fees did you use and what fees others were using, it is impossible to say.